# List of behavioral economists

Tags: microeconomics, decision-theory, behavioral-economics, environmental-economics

Even though there is a massive literature on behavioral economics, i couldn't find anywhere a list of economist that focus on that discipline.

Since i am interested in environmental economics, i would be grateful if you could mention those in academia that apply "behavioral theories" into environmental economics.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Top 10% authors in the field of Cognitive & Behavioural Economics

- https://ideas.repec.org/top/top.cbe.html

  1. Ernst Fehr, Institut für Volkswirtschaftslehre, Wirtschaftswissenschaftliche Fakutät, Universität Zürich, Zürich, Switzerland
  2. Urs Fischbacher, Fachbereich Wirtschaftswissenschaften, Universität Konstanz, Konstanz, Germany
  3. Robert Sugden, School of Economics, University of East Anglia, Norwich, United Kingdom
  4. Andrew Schotter, Department of Economics, New York University (NYU), New York City, New York (USA)
  5. Peter P. Wakker, Econometrisch Instituut, Faculteit der Economische Wetenschappen, Erasmus Universiteit Rotterdam, Rotterdam, Netherlands
  6. ...

And the other 140 economists.

Comment: Don't forget the economists of the past, whose shoulders Fehr and Co. stand on today! John M. Keynes, John F. Nash, John von Neumann, and about 10 more Nobel laureates who came after.

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to provide a list of behavioral economists, because many researchers use behavioral insights in their own field (development, labor, ...). And restricting attention to scholars who focus exclusively on behavioral economics does not help much: it would be akin to trying to provide a list of macroeconomists, or of game theorists, there are simply too many of them.

Regarding behavioral environmental economics, I suggest you have a look at the paper "Behavioral environmental economics: promises and challenges" by Rachel Croson and Nicolas Treich, which reviews and discusses this field.

Comment: I am aware of that paper :)